# How to remove the language indicator from the Windows 8.1 taskbar via command line?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1

So, a game I play for some bizarre reason causes the language selector to show up on my taskbar every single time I run it after a reboot. My PC is English (UK) and the game adds English (US).

Once I remove it the first time, it stays removed until reboot. Is there a way I can do it via CMD so I can just have a batch run after I run the game?

To be specific, I am looking for how to do:
R-click Taskbar > Properties > Taskbar > Customize... > Turn System Icons on or off > Input Indicator > Off

via a direct command line, I don't want to make a script to automate the clicks.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the following two lines into Notepad, save them as HideLang.reg and merge it into the registry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\CTF\LangBar]
"ShowStatus"=dword:00000003
```

You'll need to log off then log back on or reboot the computer for this change to take effect.